# Compactness of a subset of bounded differentiable functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $(C^2(\mathbb{R}), ||\cdot||_\infty)$ be a set of continuously differentiable, uniformly bounded functions with uniformly bounded derivatives. Is a subset
$$
S = \{a\in C^2(\mathbb{R}) : a(x) \le a_0 < 0, \; \forall x\}
$$
compact?

---

So far I could only find that $C^2(\mathbb{R})$ is complete (not 100% sure about $S$ though). I had two ideas about going further from here:

1. Because compactness follows from completeness and total boundedness, what is left is to show that $S$ is totally bounded. I can't figure how to do that
2. Another way I thought about is to use Arzela-Ascoli theorem, but $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact so I can't just use the original theorem

If it is indeed compact, I want to generalize this to a set of matrix-valued functions whose range is a set of bounded negative definite matrices.

I apologize for my illiteracy, I'm no mathematician.

Comment: that set is not even bounded, since the set of functions $\{a_n(x) = -n\}_{n\in \mathbb{n}} $ is contained in it (for $n> |a_0|$).

Comment: @Thomas. Thanks, I see. I thought uniform boundedness requirement on $a(x)$ must exclude those sequences. Would adding finite lower bound $a_1$ on all $a(x)$ fix the problem?

Comment: Looked up the definition of uniform boundedness of a collection of functions again. It looks like your sequence will not be completely in $S$ because there's indeed a finite uniform lower bound $M$ on all $a(x)$, by definition. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What about the constant function $f_n$ equal to $- 2^{n}$. The sequence $(f_n)_n$ is not bounded and $f_n$'s are eventually in $S$, yet $f$ is not. So $S$ is not even bounded, let alone compact.

Comment: Oh, sry, I forgot $\le$. Edited the question

Comment: No need to edit anything (I forsaw you doing this) because your set is not even bounded. $f_n = -2^n$ for instance...

Comment: Are you going to edit your question each time I give you another counter example ?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to understand what are the required constraints on $S$ for the thing to be compact. I thought that uniform boundedness requirement on $a(x)$ should exclude the sequences like $-2^n$ from the game. P.S: Don't worry, I'll accept your answer, I just wish you gave some information about how to constrain $S$ to get what I need

Comment: What about adding a constant lower bound $a_1<a(x)<a_0<0$? Looks bounded then...